# Не работает jQuery с простейшим функционалом

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, php

Делал для теста такой вот обработчик события keyup. В итоге при нажатии любой клавиши в текстовом поле ничего не происходит. Вот файл html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

<input id="search_name" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Введите имя пользователя..." autocomplete="off" style="width:96%; margin-left:2%;">
```

Вот код javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#search_name").keyup(function(key){
    alert('1');
}
}
```

Подскажите, в чем тут ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да вроде все [работает](http://jsfiddle.net/DEmT4/). Просто вы забыли закрыть скобку `);` в конце скрипта.

Comment: Огромное спасибо) Невнимательность - мой конек

Comment: Не за что) я в школе в 2+2 ошибалась, а интегралы и пр. как семечки щелкала)